# Change URL to remove query string variable name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, url-rewriting, routes

I have an MVC application and the url looks like this;

```
/celebritypage/celebrityname=Elma Fudd
```

What I'd like is to only have;

```
/celebritypage/Elma Fudd
```

Is this possible within routing?

Comment: This article from Scott Gu should provide all the information you need: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx

Comment: Are the spaces intentional? They are non-standard for URLs. Also, the path with an equals is also pretty non-standard. Are you asking about routing a celebrity in general, or specifically about using spaces?

Comment: the spaces are irrelevant.  they will be %20, i just wanted to illistrate what i was after

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, something like this should work:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "RouteName",
    "celebritypage/{name}",
    new { controller = "celebritypage", action = "celebrityname" }
);
```

Then make sure your controller action is ready for the parameter:

```
//inside celebritypage Controller

public ActionResult celebrityname(string name) {
    //code
    return View("ViewName");
}
```